# Unable to output value of a map

Tags: apex, map, list

Declaring a map with list as value and getting the output for value as:
"common.apex.runtime.impl.ScalarList@7861"

**Page**:

```
<apex:page controller="abc123ex">
    <apex:outputPanel >{!retrieve}</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**:

```
public class abc123ex {
    public map<integer, list<integer>> getRetrieve() {
        map<integer, list<integer>> m = new map<integer, list<integer>>{
            1 => new list<integer>{1,2,3},
            2 => new list<integer>{1,2,3}
        };
        return m;
    }
}
```

**Actual Output**:

```
{1=common.apex.runtime.impl.ScalarList@7861, 2=common.apex.runtime.impl.ScalarList@7861}
```

**Expected Output**:

```
{1=(1, 2, 3), 2=(1, 2, 3)}
```

Thanks

Comment: I am able to run this code no problem through Execute Anonymous.

Comment: Interesting, I dont know why I am getting that error.  Let me try again. Thanks

Comment: Adrian, Can you please run that piece of code on VF page and see if you are able to get the result. Thanks

Comment: Are you getting an error or is the output being printed out as you have it shown in your question?

Comment: I am sorry that is not the error but i am getting that in the output. "corrected in question as well"

Comment: So to clarify, you are not getting an error. Instead the output is a appearing as `{1=common.apex.runtime.impl.ScalarList@7861, 2=common.apex.runtime.impl.ScalarList@7861}` when it should something like be `{1=(1, 2, 3), 2=(1, 2, 3)}`?

Comment: Yes. That's what I am trying

Comment: try using open and closed '(" instead of brackets around `new list<integer>{1,2,3}`. That's what the scalar is referring to. You're creating 2 scalar lists in using the brackets if I'm not mistaken which are both the same since they use the same syntax as in start and end points of 1,2,3.

Comment: So I corrected to `'a' => (new list<integer>{1,2,3}) ` but still the same error. Please correct me if anything is wrong. Thanks

Comment: I think this might be ok, try changing your output to {!retrieve[1]} and see if you get what you expect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think Visualforce can "pretty print" Maps the same way it would in the console. You need to create some other way to display the values from the Map.

This code works as expected:

```
public class abc123ex {
  public String getRetrieve() {
     map<integer, list<integer>> m = new map<integer, list<integer>>{
        1 => new list<integer>{1,2,3},
        2 => new list<integer>{1,2,3}
     };
     return String.valueOf(m);
   }
}
```